# I need to create a Query for comparing two columns in same table

Tags: sql

I need to create a SQL Query in which i have to compare the values in two columns of the same table in such a manner that the sum of values in one column is equal to a static value in another column.

e.g, there are 4 columns

```
1.) Internal ID
2.) Plan_id 
3.) Numerator value
4.) Denominator value.
```

So wherever Internal ID and Plan_id are unique, i need to add up the corresponding values for numerator column and then compare it with denominator column.

for ex:

```
INTERNAL_ID      PLAN_ID         NUMERATOR       DENOMINATOR
12345            10                30               50
12345            10                20               50
12345            20                10               50
34566            10                10               10
```

Here i need to pick up the internal id 12345 as its sum of numerator value `(30+20) = 50 (denominator value)` for unique combination of plan_id and internal_id.

Comment: please adjust your identation (4 spaces) this is to hard to read

Comment: How 3rd row Denominator has 50???

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please include the output you expect and consider rewording your question statement.

Comment: 3rd and 4th row are added just to create extra rows. first two rows are of need because here internal id and plan_id are same. here sum of numerator value(30+20) is equals to denominator value i.e, 50.

Comment: @user3458680 Which Database are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT INTERNAL_ID,
       PLAN_ID,
       NUMERATOR,
       Sum(NUMERATOR) Over (Partition By INTERNAL_ID,PLAN_ID Order By (Select Null)) AS DENOMINATOR
FROM Table1
```